# AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm attempting to use AutoMapper for the first time. The GSMSite maps fine, but I get an error when trying to map the GSMUnit:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Do I need to specify a relationship between GSMSite and GSMUnits?

Domain class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }    
    public string Telephone { get; set; } 
    public bool PasswordReset { get; set; } = false;
    public virtual ICollection<GSMSite> GSMSites { get; set; }
}

public class GSMSite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GSMUnit> GSMUnits { get; set; }
}

public class GSMUnit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Firmware { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNum { get; set; }
    public int GSMSiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual GSMSite GSMSite { get; set; }
}
```

Contract class:

```
public class GSMResponse
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Model { get; set; }
     public string Firmware { get; set; }
     public string TelephoneNum { get; set; }
}

public class SiteResponse
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

}
```

Mapping:

```
public DomainToResponseProfile()
{
        CreateMap<GSMSite, SiteResponse>();
        CreateMap<GSMUnit, GSMResponse>();           
}
```

Comment: The data fields in AutoMapper exceptions usually have more details on the specific failure. Can you see additional info in the exception?

Comment: Errors like these are why I prefer Omu.ValueInjecter over AutoMapper. https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter

Comment: Actually `exception.ToString()` will tell you exactly what map is missing.